# How do I keep enemies of the same class from "sharing" health?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is probably a pretty basic question. I'm pretty new with swift and I've gone through a couple of books and am now trying to learn by doing. I was making a game where zombies are randomly spawned continuously and the player's car runs over them until they die. The problem is that all of the zombie child nodes seem to share the same health and I'm not sure how to correct it.

My zombie class is initialized with 20 health as indicated below:

```
class Zombie: SKSpriteNode, GameSprite {
var initialSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 30, height: 54)
var textureAtlas:SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Zombies")
var health:Int = 20
```

When hit, the zombies take 4 damage on each collision until they die:

```
func takeDamage() {
    self.health -= 4
    print("zombie has", health, "health")
    if self.health == 0 {
        die()
    }
}
```

It works fine for the first zombie and the health decreases five times and it dies, but then the health remains at 0 when the second zombie is spawned, and continues to decrease negatively for each zombie as the car continues to collide with them. Of course, none of the zombies after the first ever die because the health is already less than zero. I understand why it is happening, but I'm not sure how to reset the health at 20 for each spawn and give each zombie independent health values. I have tried manually setting the health variable in my spawn function but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
func spawnEnemy(){
    let enemiesToSpawn = arc4random_uniform(11) + 1
    var enemiesSpawned = UInt32(0)
    while enemiesSpawned < enemiesToSpawn {
        var spawnLocationX = player.position.x + CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(200)) + 900
        var spawnLocationY = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(415)) - 240
        let zombie = Zombie()
        zombie.position = CGPoint(x: spawnLocationX, y: spawnLocationY)
        zombie.zPosition = 1
        zombie.position.x += 33
        zombie.health = 20
        self.addChild(zombie)
        enemiesSpawned += 1

    }

}
```

Comment: What's your theory as to why it happens?

Comment: Give a unique id to each copy with userData.

Comment: where is takeDamage defined? and where is it called.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I think the problem has to do with Zombie class sharing the same reference. My guess is that it has something to do with the nature of SKNode. Try:         if let zombie = self.zombie?.copy() as? SKShapeNode {
            self.addChild(zombie)
        }

define zombie as a local property in your class, then copy it when you need it.